# LoadRunner parameterization multiple columns

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance-testing

I am using LoadRunner true client AJAX protocol for recording purpose.

I have successfully recorded the script and tried to create a parameter in a table (text file) containing username and password as column names.

The text file has a name username by itself.

In the Vuser script when I create a JavaScript variable like this:

```
login_name=LR.getParam("username")
```

I replaced the username with above parameter and it works fine, but for password I am not able to create a separate variable to pass. It is passing the same username into password box and login fails.

What is my mistake, what do I need to change in the parameter list to update the password?

Answer (score 0):

loadrunner encrypts the password by default look for lr_decrypt in the script , right click on the argument inside this function and select restore original value .

now select the restored value and parametrise it. it works:)